# Run java script utilizing acm.program package from terminal

Tags: java, terminal, acm-java-libraries

I am trying to run the following script - [source of code here](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/rationale/ProgramPackage.html)- on my terminal:

```java
import acm.program.*;

public class Add2 extends Program {

   public void run() {
      println("This program adds two numbers.");
      int n1 = readInt("Enter n1: ");
      int n2 = readInt("Enter n2: ");
      int total = n1 + n2;
      println("The total is " + total + ".");
   }
}
```

I then compile and run the code using these two steps on my terminal:

```
javac -classpath acm.jar Add2.java
java Add2
```

The compilation indicates no errors , but when I try to run the script, I get the following error:
`Error: Could not find or load main class Add2`.
I'm fairly new at working with Java so any advice on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) can only execute code with a [`main`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN) method. Code cannot be executed without a `main` method but it can still be compiled (as you noticed), thus it is mandatory to use a `main` method or you will run into `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Simply add this to your code (you don't need the comments):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // This class is mandatory to be executed by the JVM.
    // You don't need to do anything in here, since you're subclassing ConsoleProgram,
    // which invokes the run() method.
}
```

Btw, since you're overriding `Program#run()` you need to add [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html) as annotation. Also, as you're only using the console, subclassing [`ConsoleProgram`](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/ConsoleProgram.html) would be enough.